# Not Getting the same result when user is clicked? -AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am coming to this problem when I have a listing of users, and for instance: when you click on "user1", it takes to user1 details page. BUT, when you click on "user2", it shows "user1" details page instead of "User2" details page. Can anyone see my code, of what I did wrong? Thank you. **Check the images below.**

[Home.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhAqQ.png)  [About.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXfF3.png)

> Here is my code.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Portal">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>



      <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@0.12.0" data-semver="0.12.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>




    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />



  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
          <h3>Portal</h3>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
          <div ng-view>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controllers/LawyerController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
      <script src="js/services/lawyers.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

> About.html

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
```

```
  <a class="back" href="#/lawyer">Back</a>
  <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
    Edit
  </button>


  <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">Save</button>


  <a class="delete" ng-click="confirmClick() && confirmedAction()" confirm-click>Confirm</a>


<!-- Our Laywers details -->



<div class="people-view" >



  <h2 class="name">{{person.firstName}}</h2>
    <h2 class="name">{{person.lastName}}</h2>

  <span class="title">{{person.email}}</span>

  <span class="date">{{person.website}} </span>



</div>

<!-- the form -->


<div class="list-view">


  <form>
    <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">

  <legend>Basic Info</legend>

  <b>First Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="person.firstName">
  <br>
  <b>Last Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="person.lastName">
  <br>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <input type="email" ng-model="person.email">


  <br>
  <b>Website:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="person.website">

    </fieldset> 


  </form>



</div>
</div>
```

> Home.html

```
<form name="myForm">
<!-- Search field-->
<label>Search
<input type="text" size="35" ng-model="userSearch">
</label>

</form>

<br/>
<!-- Add a filter -->
<label>Filters</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">+ Add Filter</button>
<hr>
<legend>Users</legend>







<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-repeat="person in userInfo.lawyers | filter:{id: lawyerId}"> >



   <a href="#/lawyer/{{ person.id }}">

    <!--<img ng-src="{{person.imageUrl}}"/>-->
    <span class="name">{{person.firstName}} </span>
    <span class="name">{{person.lastName}} </span>

   <p class="title">{{person.email}} </p>
  <!--<span class="date">{{person.website}} </span>-->


</a>


</div>
```

> App.js

```
var app = angular.module("Portal", ['ngRoute',  'ui.bootstrap' ]);



    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.inactive = true;

        $scope.confirmedAction = function() {

        isConfirmed.splice($scope.person.id, 1);

        location.href = '#/lawyer';





    }

});




app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/lawyer", {
                controller: "HomeController",
                templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
            })
            .when("/lawyer/:id", {
                controller: "LawyerController",
                templateUrl: "partials/about.html"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/lawyer'

            });

});
```

> HomeController

```
var isConfirmed = false;
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, people, $http) {
    if (!isConfirmed) {
        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {

            $scope.userInfo = response.data;






            isConfirmed = $scope.userInfo;


            console.log($scope.person);

        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
});
```

> LawyerController

```
app.controller('LawyerController', ['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
    function ($scope, people, $routeParams) {

            people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {

                 $scope.lawyerId = $routeParams.id;

                console.log($scope.userInfo);

            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            });

    }]);
```

> Services

```
    app.factory('people', ['$http', function($http) {
    var userInfo = { //object
        getUserInfo: function () {
            return $http.get('https://************/*****/**/********');

        }
    };
    return userInfo;
}]);
```

**PS: Let me know if you need more explanation of my problem. Once again, thank you for your time and help.**

Comment: You're not passing anything to `getUserInfo`, how does your ajax call know what parameters to send to with the AJAX call to get the right person's data? You can leverage the $routeParams service to grab the ID and pass it to your function.

Comment: you are showing the form via `ng-repeat="person in userInfo.lawyers | limitTo : 1"` in `About.html`?

Comment: Well, if you see in my services, I am grabbing the data from the backend, that is returning back a result. Can you please, show me some code how to fix this problem? So, I can understand it well.

Comment: @AgamBanga is that error causing it? But, I tried to remove the limitTo, I get duplicate forms. How can we fix it?

Comment: @JustinS. you need to filter the array according to the id in the list

Comment: @AgamBanga yes it is like that of what you see.

Comment: @AgamBanga Can you please show me a snippet prior to my code, so I can understand it well.

Comment: `$scope.lawyerId = $routeParams.id` in controller, and then `userInfo.lawyers | filter:{id: lawyerId}` in your view should work.

Comment: @mhodges should I put the $scope.lawyerId in LawerController or HomeController?

Comment: @JustinS. Well, if you think about it (and look at your route definitions), the id is only being passed through on the `/lawyers/:id` route, which uses the `LawyerController`, so `LawyerController` will be the only one with access to the id via the `$routeParams` service.

Comment: @mhodges can you see my updated question, if I did it right. Because when I go to the details page, I am getting a duplicate listing.

Comment: @JustinS. I believe `filter` does partial matches by default. You will need to pass `true` as the second parameter into the `filter` to force an exact match. it would look like this: `(userInfo.lawyers | filter:{id: lawyerId}:true)`. If you are still getting duplicates, then you have duplicates in your data. Also, you should do your filtering in the controller, not on the view, as I mentioned under Agam's answer

Comment: @mhodges can you please check my updated question, to see if I implement it right

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**

You have to set a  function which have to get a single user info

```
var userInfo = { //object
    getUserInfo: function () {
        return $http.get('https://************/*****/**/********');
    },
     getSingleUserInfo: function (userId) {
        return $http.get('https://************/*****/**/********?userId='+userId);
    }
};
```

Change your LawyerController as below

```
app.controller('LawyerController', ['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
function ($scope, people, $routeParams) {
    var userId = $routeParams.id;
    people.getSingleUserInfo(userId).then(function (response) {
        $scope.userInfo = response.data;
        console.log($scope.userInfo);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
}]);
```

You can now from your backend get a single user info with the param "userId"

**OPTION 2**

Store the selected user in $rootScope as below

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $rootScope, people, $http) {
    $rootScope.selectedUser = null; //Add this line
    if (!isConfirmed) {
        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
            $scope.userInfo = response.data;
            isConfirmed = $scope.userInfo;
            console.log($scope.person);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
});
```

Change This line from Home.html

```
<a href="#/lawyer/{{ person.id }}">
```

to

```
<a href="#/lawyer/{{ person.id }}" ng-click="selectedUser=person">
```

At this point you don't need ng-repeat in your About.html view because the selected person is in $rootScope.selectedUser. You just have to replace "person" with "selectedUser"

Comment: `$http.get('https://************/*****/**/********).then(response => response.data.find(user => user.id === userId)` would work if they are reading a JSON file and not doing server-side processing.

Comment: @AmadouBeye I tried your method. But getting this console error:       
   Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=peopleProvider%20%3C-%20people%20%3C-%20HomeController

Comment: @AmadouBeye that is referring to HomeController

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `router param id` in scope variable so that you can filter it by that id in the html.You can use like this

```
app.controller('LawyerController', ['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
    function ($scope, people, $routeParams) {
            $scope.lawyer_id = $routeParams.id;
            people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {

                $scope.userInfo = response.data;

                console.log($scope.userInfo);

            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            });

    }]);
```

In **HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="person in userInfo.lawyers | filter:{ id: lawyer_id }">
```

Comment: While this will work, I think it may be important to explain (in full context) why this is not the correct approach. The OP is looking to show details for a single lawyer, so (ideally) only 1 lawyer would be returned, but if they are not doing any server-side processing, and simply reading a JSON file, then the filtering should be done in the controller or in the service and not in the view. `$scope.lawyer = userInfo.lawyers.find(lawyer=>lawyer.id === lawyer_id);` and then simply say `{{lawyer.firstName}} {{lawyer.lastName}}`, etc. in the view.

Comment: He don't need to load all users for this route but only the selected user

Comment: @AmadouBeye yes, for instance: When "User2" is clicked show "User2" details page **only**.

Comment: yes i agree, i was answering according to the current setup. Basically he needs to fetch the another api for single user. Also we don't know what else he is getting in the api as he is using `userInfo.lawyers` for printing users. there must be separate objects in the userinfo

Comment: @AgamBanga Well, I have only one object that has an array of 5.

Comment: @JustinS. then you need to create a new service which fetch only single user id & then remove the `ng-repeat` & simply access the `userInfo` object

Comment: @AgamBanga Can you please show me some code prior to my code, So I can understand it well.